citus high availability setup with patroni
We want to setup patroni HA setup with 3 coordinator, 2 worker node 1 & 2 worker node 2.
I am getting system id mismatch when i start 2nd coordinator. First one is running fine, only facing issue while running the 2nd coordinator while joining the cluster.
Below is my patroni.yml file.
I tried deleting data directory and also removing key from etcd and start again. But it is the same issue.
Also while initialising slave, i removed method: initdb and ititdb config as well.
scope: demo
name: ${INSTANCE_NAME}
namespace: /service/

citus:
  group: ${CITUS_GROUP}   # 0 for coordinator and 1, 2, 3, etc for workers
  database: citus  # must be the same on all nodes

restapi:
  listen: 0.0.0.0:8008
  connect_address: ${INVENTORY_HOSTNAME}:8008

etcd3:
  hosts: ${PATRONI_ETCD_HOSTS}

bootstrap:
  method: initdb
  dcs:
    ttl: 30
    loop_wait: 10
    retry_timeout: 10
    maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
    master_start_timeout: 300
    synchronous_mode: false
    synchronous_mode_strict: false
    synchronous_node_count: 1
    postgresql:
      use_pg_rewind: true
      use_slots: true
      parameters:
        max_connections: 1000
        superuser_reserved_connections: 5
        password_encryption: md5
        max_locks_per_transaction: 512
        max_prepared_transactions: 0
        huge_pages: try
        shared_buffers: 512MB
        effective_cache_size: 1024MB
        work_mem: 512MB
        maintenance_work_mem: 256MB
        checkpoint_timeout: 15min
        checkpoint_completion_target: 0.9
        min_wal_size: 2GB
        max_wal_size: 8GB
        wal_buffers: 16MB
        default_statistics_target: 1000
        seq_page_cost: 1
        random_page_cost: 1.1
        effective_io_concurrency: 200
        synchronous_commit: on
        autovacuum: on
        autovacuum_max_workers: 5
        autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor: 0.01
        autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor: 0.01
        autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit: 500
        autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay: 2
        autovacuum_naptime: 1s
        max_files_per_process: 4096
        archive_mode: on
        archive_timeout: 1800s
        archive_command: cd .
        wal_level: logical
        wal_keep_size: 2GB
        max_wal_senders: 10
        max_replication_slots: 10
        hot_standby: on
        wal_log_hints: on
        wal_compression: on
        shared_preload_libraries: pg_stat_statements,auto_explain
        pg_stat_statements.max: 10000
        pg_stat_statements.track: all
        pg_stat_statements.track_utility: false
        pg_stat_statements.save: true
        auto_explain.log_min_duration: 10s
        auto_explain.log_analyze: true
        auto_explain.log_buffers: true
        auto_explain.log_timing: false
        auto_explain.log_triggers: true
        auto_explain.log_verbose: true
        auto_explain.log_nested_statements: true
        auto_explain.sample_rate: 0.01
        track_io_timing: on
        log_lock_waits: on
        log_temp_files: 0
        track_activities: on
        track_activity_query_size: 4096
        track_counts: on
        track_functions: all
        log_checkpoints: on
        logging_collector: on
        log_truncate_on_rotation: on
        log_rotation_age: 1d
        log_rotation_size: 0
        log_line_prefix: '%t [%p-%l] %r %q%u@%d '
        log_filename: postgresql-%a.log
        log_directory: /var/log/postgresql
        hot_standby_feedback: on
        max_standby_streaming_delay: 30s
        wal_receiver_status_interval: 10s
        idle_in_transaction_session_timeout: 10min
        jit: off
        max_worker_processes: 24
        max_parallel_workers: 10
        max_parallel_workers_per_gather: 2
        max_parallel_maintenance_workers: 2
        tcp_keepalives_count: 10
        tcp_keepalives_idle: 300
        tcp_keepalives_interval: 30
        citus.enable_change_data_capture: 'on'
        citus.max_client_connections: 300
      slots:
        demo_slot:
          type: logical
          database: demo
          plugin: pgoutput

  initdb:
    - encoding: UTF8
    - locale: en_US.UTF-8
    - data-checksums

  pg_hba:
    - host replication ${PATRONI_REPLICATION_USERNAME} 127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

postgresql:
  listen: 0.0.0.0:5432
  connect_address: ${INVENTORY_HOSTNAME}:5432
  use_unix_socket: true
  data_dir: /data/postgresql
  bin_dir: /usr/lib/postgresql/16/bin
  config_dir: /etc/postgresql/16/main
  pgpass: /tmp/pgpass
  authentication:
    replication:
      username: ${PATRONI_REPLICATION_USERNAME}
      password: ${PATRONI_REPLICATION_PASSWORD}
    superuser:
      username: ${PATRONI_SUPERUSER_USERNAME}
      password: ${PATRONI_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD}
  parameters:
    unix_socket_directories: /var/run/postgresql
  remove_data_directory_on_rewind_failure: false
  remove_data_directory_on_diverged_timelines: false

  create_replica_methods:
    - basebackup
  basebackup:
    max-rate: '1000M'
    checkpoint: fast

watchdog:
  mode: automatic
  device: /dev/watchdog
  safety_margin: 5

tags:
  nosync: false
  noloadbalance: false
  nofailover: false
  clonefrom: false
``

